# Time to Interactive Vs First CPU Idle

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, lighthouse

What's the difference between Time to Interactive Vs First CPU Idle.For me in all the reports Time to Interactive is always > First CPU Idle.

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/time-to-interactive) define Time to Interactive as:

> The Time to Interactive (TTI) metric measures how long it takes a page
>   to become interactive. "Interactive" is defined as the point where:
>
> - The page has displayed useful content, which is measured with First Contentful Paint.
> - Event handlers are registered for most visible page elements.
> - The page responds to user interactions within 50 milliseconds.

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/first-cpu-idle) define First CPU Idle as:

> The First CPU Idle metric measures when a page is minimally
>   interactive:
>
> - Most, but maybe not all, UI elements on the screen are interactive.
> - The page responds, on average, to most user input in a reasonable
>     amount of time.

The difference being that **first CPU time** measures when a page is minimally interactive, and **time to interactive** measures how long it takes a page to become interactive.

Comment: so 1st CPU idle means user can start entering input into a form, and TTI means that the page can start to respond to user’s input?

Comment: From those definitions, I'd expect that time-to-interactive would always be lesser or equal than "first CPU idle". However, I got a larger TTI (3.3s) than "first cpu idle" (3s) in a Lighthouse check I have just done. How is that possible?